# One PHP file for multiple pages?

Tags: php

I'm creating a dashboard which will have different pages for different purposes. I'm thinking if wether I should have one PHP file for each page or one for all the pages?

Pros to me is:

- One file with all functions to simplify work (less files - less clutter)

Cons:

- Longer loading time because one large file?

I guess my major question is if there really is a major advantage/disadvantage to either?

Comment: You should always consider to break in small parts .. lets say you have bug on one page then will down all your pages ... it a simple example

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI That's very true

Answer (score 1):

Using a building irony, nobody says we can't pile 50 rooms one above another instead of spreading 25 on two levels!

1) Putting all files in one file is less clutter indeed, but more likely to break everything once something goes wrong at some point.

2) Depending on how many files you have to create, I would advise to separate functionality in multiple files. If one breaks, others may still work.

3) I love Ajax  in that it can reduce all this "clutter issue", keeping in mind though, that everything will rely on your Ajax function being well done and securely put together

:)

Comment: Yes very true. For clutter issue you can use AJAX or the javascript. Ex - Angular js is an example of SPA(Single page application) which will avoid clutter issue.